# Software Won't Open

Tags: windows-7, printer

I've got a program on my computer, Canon MF Toolbox 4.9. It's used with my printer to initiate scans, settings for those scans, and misc operations, and allows the settings to be changed on the software instead of pressing buttons on the printer.

A few weeks ago it stopped opening. I set it to run as Administrator because nothing else worked, and it continued to open. A few days ago, it stopped opening altogether.

Now the process in task manager still exists and runs when I open the icon, but the window with the options does not show up. I've tried ending the process and opening the icon again, but the process just starts again with no window opening.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Windows 7, 64 bit, I am the administrator, printer is a Canon ImageClass Mf4270. No other programs should be interfering with this software. I have already tried uninstalling and reinstalling, no change.

Comment: Have you attempted to uninstall and reinstall the software? The [latest version](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/support/consumer/printers_multifunction/imageclass_series/imageclass_mf4270#DriversAndSoftware) is 4.9.1.1 dated 8/2014. Is that the version you are using?

Comment: Ah sorry, forgot to mention that. Yes, I did uninstall and reinstall latest version. There was no change.

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall anti-virus software? Some programs can inject their own DLL into executable. Also, if it is possible, please gather stack information of the process (with [ProcessThreadsView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/process_threads_view.html) for example).

Comment: Disabling the virus scanner software didn't do anything. The only stack information that ProcessThreadsView game me was the following:   00000000`0095F730 00000000`77BEA220  -> Delaying execution failed with status 0x%08lx

Comment: Any error messages in the Event Viewer related to this? You could try running `SFC /scannow` from an elevated command prompt to ensure all the Windows system files are OK.